# How do I specify minutes range between 55 and 60 (both inclusive) in kusto

Tags: kql

So, I was storing the current time in a variable and extracting the minute for it.

For eg

```
let current_time=now():
let current_minute=datetime_part("minute", current_time);
RequiredTime=iff(current_minute between (55 .. 00), variable1, variable2)
```

So, I want to check range between 55th and the 60th minute. Should I refer to it as 00 (I doubt this since ideally it should get confused looking for a range between 55 and 00) or is there any other way to handle this case?

Comment: Feels like [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please share more details on your original challenge.

Comment: That **was** a request for clarification. Please note that I downvoted your answer (for a very good reason), not your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let current_time=now();
let current_minute=datetime_part("minute", current_time);
let current_minute60=iff(current_minute==00, 60, current_minute);
RequiredTime=iff(current_minute between (55 .. current_minute60), variable1, variable2);
```

This takes care of the edge case.

Comment: It's O.K. to figure out a solution to your own question and post it. It's not O.K. to post a code with **typos**, **syntax errors**, **logical errors** & **missing declarations**. Create a reproducible code and test it before posting it.

Comment: O.K. I don't see many guys posting the whole code. They post snippets and answers are also in snippets of code. The above is more like it. I was asking for an approach more than the step by step code in this case. Maybe you could have clarified it before not helping in any manner. It would be better if you are kinder in your response next time. Please help people on the platform instead of bashing them for posting them. FYI: I am running the above snippet currently in a prod environement.

Comment: StackOverflow is a professional platform.  The downvote is for this specific answer, due to its low quality, not for you as a StackOverflow user or as a person. Good questions contain [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Good answers almost always contain a working code, especially when they are data related (you might want to take a look on the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?tab=Newest) tag).

Comment: My bad, will ensure that next time for answers. Thanks.

Comment: Some details: **(1)** First line ends with colon (:) instead of semi-colon (;). That's the typo. **(2)** Last line misses *print* as the beginning. That's the syntax error. **(3)** *variable1* & *variable2* are not declared. That's the missing declarations. **(4)** This code returns the wrong results when the minute part equal to zero (which was the whole point of this question).

Comment: In my defence, I agree to first typo. Second, as I said it was more of a question wherein I wanted an approach for the question. Third, variable 1 and variable 2 are variables in a prototype like declared in question. Reason why I didn't print any column because I only wanted an approach for covering the range between 55th to 60th minute. I solved this by declaring the variable for that 60th minute and using it below in range. That's all I was looking for. Either this way or any other approaches one can come up with. Anyways, I do get your point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).